# Why are characters with value above 127 "padded" with 1s to be 16 bits long, while ones with values 0-127 aren't?

Tags: arduino-nano, string, array

I am using the Arduino IDE to run and monitor, with an Arduino Nano clone.
This code shows what I mean by the question:

```cpp
char foo = 127;
char bar = 128;
Serial.println(String(foo, BIN));
Serial.println(String(bar, BIN));
foo = 383;
bar = 384;
Serial.println(String(foo, BIN));
Serial.println(String(bar, BIN));
```

prints

```
1111111
1111111110000000
1111111
1111111110000000
```

It still happens if I then cast the elements to `char`, but not if I cast them to `uint8_t`:

```cpp
char foo = 127;
char bar = 128;
Serial.println(String((char)foo, BIN));
Serial.println(String((char)bar, BIN));
Serial.println(String((uint8_t)foo, BIN));
Serial.println(String((uint8_t)bar, BIN));
```

```
1111111
1111111110000000
1111111
10000000
```

It behaves the same if I do some arithmetic as well:

```cpp
char foo = 127;
char bar = 128;
Serial.println(String(foo / 64, BIN));
Serial.println(String(bar / 64, BIN));
```

```
1
1111111111111110
```

Why is this? If I assign a number bigger than 255, but smaller than 384, it behaves like for numbers below 128, but above that, it does it again, so it's obvious that only the least significant 8 bits of the value are stored as expected, but in cases where (n mod 255) > 127 (so the 8th bit is `1`) they are retrieved from memory together with another 8 bits, which are all `1`s.

**I can live without an answer to the above issue, what I really need to have confirmed is the following:**

If I were to store and retrieve a `uint16_t` as two elements of a `char[]`, it would always be safe (and not undefined behavior) if I did it as follows, right?:

```cpp
uint16_t foo = 34952;
char bar[2];
bar[0] = foo >> 8;
bar[1] = foo;
uint16_t extracted = (uint16_t((uint8_t)bar[0])) << 8 | (uint8_t)bar[1];
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the AVR platform the `char` type happens to be signed, and it can
store numbers in the range [−128, +127]. Thus, when you write

```cpp
char bar = 128;
```

You are asking to store in `bar` a number that does not fit. It then
gets reduced modulo 2<sup>8</sup> into the value that does fit, namely
−128. For the kind of manipulations you are trying to make, I would
recommend you use `uint8_t` instead of `char`.

> it would be always safe (and not undefined behavior) if I did it as
> follows

It is indeed safe, and the casts you use are needed to make it safe.

Comment: "the char type happens to be signed" Oh, right! I forgot about that before, and I thought this was the key, but now I checked, and the results for -128 are exactly the same as for 128, it also doesn't help if I try casting it to `char` (either for storing or retrieving). "use uint8_t instead of char" great that you pointed that out, I shouldn't have been using `char[]` in the first place, but originally I was using a `String` and then moved over as that would terminate at the first `NUL`. It didn't occur to me to just use `uint8_t[]`, but thankfully that still works with LoRa.

Comment: @Boba0514, 'Arduino language' has `byte` type too. it is a nicer name for uint8_t

Comment: @Juraj: “nicer” is subjective. Personally, the word “byte” evokes to me a unit of information storage equal to 8 bits, which could be used to store a signed number, an unsigned number, a collection of flags (that would have no meaningful interpretation as a number), or whatever one may want to put there. The name “uint8\_t”, while not as nicely sounding, clearly states that it holds an _unsigned_ integer. Note that Java has a `byte` data type, and it is signed.